# Changing started sequence number?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have code like this from [Xander Bakker](https://community.esri.com/message/813318-re-labeling-the-sequence-using-concatenation?commentID=813318#comment-813318)

```
def main():
    import arcpy
    fc = r'Drive:\Path\To\Source\FC'
    fld_seq = 'SequenceLbl'

    # Add field if it does not exist already
    AddField(fc, fld_seq, "TEXT", 12)

    # start update cursor to update the values in the new field
    flds = (fld_seq)
    cnt = 0
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, flds) as curs:
        for row in curs:
            cnt += 1
            km, hect = divmod(cnt, 10)
            hect_txt = "%03d" % (hect * 100,)
            lbl = "{}+{}".format(km, hect_txt)
            print cnt, hect_txt
            curs.updateRow((lbl, ))


def AddField(tbl, fld_name, fld_type, fld_length):
    if len(arcpy.ListFields(tbl, fld_name)) == 0:
        arcpy.AddField_management(tbl, fld_name, fld_type, None, None, fld_length)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the result will show
0+100
0+200
0+300
..
0+900
1+000
1+100
and so on..

I want to start from 0+000 instead of 0+100,
what code do I need to add or modify from that code?

Comment: move the statement `cnt += 1` to the end of the `for` loop?

Comment: The other alternative is to change the variable initialization to -1, so the pre-increment results it zero on the first pass. I can't recommend changing code you don't understand, especially if you don't have the correct indentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments there are two options.
As commented by [JimT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302758/changing-started-sequence-number#comment487823_302758) move the variable incrementing statement to the end of the *for* loop:

```
# start update cursor to update the values in the new field
flds = (fld_seq)
cnt = 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, flds) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        km, hect = divmod(cnt, 10)
        hect_txt = "%03d" % (hect * 100,)
        lbl = "{}+{}".format(km, hect_txt)
        print cnt, hect_txt
        curs.updateRow((lbl, ))
        cnt += 1
```

Or, as commented by [Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302758/changing-started-sequence-number#comment487836_302758), modify the initialisation of the *cnt* variable:

```
# start update cursor to update the values in the new field
flds = (fld_seq)
cnt = -1
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, flds) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        cnt += 1
        km, hect = divmod(cnt, 10)
        hect_txt = "%03d" % (hect * 100,)
        lbl = "{}+{}".format(km, hect_txt)
        print cnt, hect_txt
        curs.updateRow((lbl, ))
```

Be aware - code snippets might not follow your indentation.

Comment: Thanks guys.. solved already.. just change the cnt = 0 to cnt = -1